# Confusion about construction/destruction in vector after std::vector::clear

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }

    ~A() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> myvec;
    myvec.push_back(A());
    myvec.push_back(A());
    myvec.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
constructor
destructor
constructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
destructor
```

There are five calls to the destructor here. The first two are due to the temporaries which are passed to `push_back`. There are three other calls, but I expected one two extra calls.

`myvec.clear()` will clear only two contents so destructor of `A` should call only two times (instead of three). why there is one extra time destructor is called?

But, if I push_back only one element to the vector, instead of two, the output is as I expected.

Comment: And what about the destructors called for the temporary objects that where copied?

Comment: Reallocation takes place when capacity needs to grow from 1 to 2

Comment: add an int to A(), use different values in the constructors, and show it in constructor/destructor, just for debugging

Comment: If you would write the copy ctor it would be more clear what happens for you. :)

Comment: If you `reserve` some space, those destructions will disappear.

Comment: @black, adding a `reserve` still results in more than two destructors. The issue is the temporaries

Comment: @AaronMcDaid the question is about **one** additional call (not present when inserting only one element), not the ones that originate from temporaries

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I see now. I think the end of the question needs edited, to make clear that the first two destructions (of the temporaries) are fully understood and expected by the questioner.

Comment: @Melkon: Actually, logging something between each statement in `main` would also help a lot to understand *when* each constructor/destructor is called.

Comment: @Matthieu M. : Sure, everything is help which give you information about what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `std::vector::clear` isn't really important in this context because, when `myvec` goes out of scope, its contents will be destroyed anyway.

---

Let's consider

```
class A
{
public:
    A()  { std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
    A (const A &) { std::cout << "A(A&)\n"; }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> myvec;

    std::cout << "First\n";
    myvec.push_back(A());

    std::cout << "Second\n";
    myvec.push_back(A());

    std::cout << '\n'; // to separate the final destruction

    myvec.clear();
}
```

which outputs

```
First
constructor <-- First A _temporary_ object created when pushing_back
A(A&)       <-- vector makes a *copy* of the temporary
destructor  <-- Temporary A is destroyed
Second     
constructor <-- Second A _temporary_ object created when pushing_back
A(A&)       <-- Reallocation happens: vector can't copy because it ran out of space
A(A&)       <-- Copy of the second temporary
destructor  <-- Destroy of the temporary
destructor  <-- Destroy of the first element

destructor
destructor
```

If you `std::vector::reserve` some space, you can get rid of the copies made by the reallocation

```
std::vector<A> myvec;
myvec.reserve(8);
```

which confirms what said

```
First
constructor
A(A&) 
destructor
Second
constructor
A(A&) 
destructor
```

`push_back` is still making copies of the parameter: this can be further optimized by making your class moveable.

```
A(A&&) noexcept = default;
A& operator=(A&&) noexcept = default;

First
constructor
destructor
Second
constructor
destructor
```

Comment: Thnks a lot for ur detailed explanation @black. .

Comment: Move semantics and `= default` are only available from C++11 onward.

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely due to the reallocation that takes place between the first and the second `push_back`. If you `reserve` some space ahead of time, then [the deallocations are going to be `2`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a799480fc535113) after the two `push_back`s, as you have expected.

Answer (score 5):

Try this slightly modified version of your program. There is now a copy constructor and an optional `reserve` (see comment in the program). It will be a lot clearer what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class A
{
  public:
  A()            { cout << " constructor" << endl; }
  A(const A & a) { cout << " copy constructor" << endl; }
  ~A()           { cout << " destructor" << endl; }
};



int main()
{
  vector<A> myvec;

  // myvec.reserve(100);                   // <<< remove comment to see the difference

  cout << "pushback 1" << endl;
  myvec.push_back(A());

  cout << "pushback 2"  << endl;
  myvec.push_back(A());

  cout << "pushback 3"  << endl;
  myvec.push_back(A());

  cout << "clear"  << endl;
  myvec.clear();
  cout << "end clear" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid C++ because your copy constructor takes a non-const reference, but the `push_back` calls need to copy a temporary, which cannot bind to a non-const reference. It compiles with VC++ because reasons.